# Puzzle #4: Enigmatic Entry

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language

A detective is showing off notes to the lieutenant of the precinct he works at. Being a more classy investigator, he keeps a journal of notes that he separates by case. However, in order to ensure that no one copies and/or plagiarizes his work, he takes the notes in a different way.

Because he is a fan of linguistic riddles, he writes his entries down in a way that can only make sense through thinking about what the entry is truly saying. In other words, it looks like nonsense to the average human.

He(the detective)was instructed with finding where a certain knife was hidden, as it was the murder weapon of the case being investigated. The entry showing how he deduced the location went like this.

Dans
El parque
Amusant
Debajo de
La montagne russe

So... where is the knife hidden?

Comment: This is the last thing I will be posting until Friday night when I get back from vacation. See you guys?

Answer (score 2):

Well,

> Google translate for French and Spanish gives you:

This

> In
> the park 
> amusant
>  under
>  roller coaster

So

> It is in the amusement park under the roller coaster.

Comment: @XavierStanton, Is my answer close? :)